# USB HID device read with C vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, node-red

I am not able to read temperature from my Temper1 USB temp sensor via node red

Here is my code:

```
var HID = require('node-hid');
var readCommand=[0x01, 0x80, 0x33, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];
exports.readTemperatures=function(devices) {
};

exports.getDevices=function() {
 var devices=HID.devices();
 var list=[];
 devices.forEach(function(item) {
   if(item.product==="TEMPerV1.4" && 
      item.vendorId===3141 &&
    //1 returns path
      //item.interface===0){  list.push(item.path);
    //2 returns device
    item.interface===0){  list.push(item);
  }
 });
 return list;
}

exports.readTemperature=function(path, callback, converter){
 if(!converter) {
  converter=exports.toDegreeCelcius;
 }
 var device = new HID.HID(path);
 device.write(readCommand);
 device.read(function(err,response){
   if(err) {
    callback.call(this,err,null); 
   } else {
    callback.call(this,null, converter(response[2],response[3]));
   }
 });
}

exports.toDegreeCelcius=function(hiByte, loByte) {
 var sign = hiByte & (1 << 7);
 var temp = ((hiByte & 0x7F) << 8) | loByte;
 if (sign) {
    temp = -temp;
 }
 return temp * 125.0 / 32000.0;
}
```

The code was provided from https://www.npmjs.org/package/temper1
But I have edited it since their temperature sensor is a bit different in version and I found the interface in code is different. hence changed interface to 0 from 1 and changed the device name. hence I can read device detail via node red. But my doubt is probably due to USB read commands my code is not working. But I am unable to detect what would be correct one, I mean how to change. I am giving one C code which works well if running from ubuntu terminal:

```
#include <usb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h> 


#define VERSION "0.0.1"

#define VENDOR_ID  0x0c45
#define PRODUCT_ID 0x7401

#define INTERFACE1 0x00
#define INTERFACE2 0x01

const static int reqIntLen=8;
const static int reqBulkLen=8;
const static int endpoint_Int_in=0x82; /* endpoint 0x81 address for IN */
const static int endpoint_Int_out=0x00; /* endpoint 1 address for OUT */
const static int endpoint_Bulk_in=0x82; /* endpoint 0x81 address for IN */
const static int endpoint_Bulk_out=0x00; /* endpoint 1 address for OUT */
const static int timeout=5000; /* timeout in ms */

const static char uTemperatura[] = { 0x01, 0x80, 0x33, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
const static char uIni1[] = { 0x01, 0x82, 0x77, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
const static char uIni2[] = { 0x01, 0x86, 0xff, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

static int bsalir=1;
static int debug=0;
static int seconds=5;
static int formato=0;
static int mrtg=0;


/* EDIT THIS TO SUBSTRACT x DEGRESS CELSIUS FROM THE OUTPUT! - SOME TEMPer DEVICES SHOW TOO MUCH */
static int substract = 0;


void bad(const char *why) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Fatal error> %s\n",why);
        exit(17);
}


usb_dev_handle *find_lvr_winusb();

void usb_detach(usb_dev_handle *lvr_winusb, int iInterface) {
        int ret;

    ret = usb_detach_kernel_driver_np(lvr_winusb, iInterface);
    if(ret) {
        if(errno == ENODATA) {
            if(debug) {
                printf("Device already detached\n");
            }
        } else {
            if(debug) {
                printf("Detach failed: %s[%d]\n",
                       strerror(errno), errno);
                printf("Continuing anyway\n");
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(debug) {
            printf("detach successful\n");
        }
    }
} 

usb_dev_handle* setup_libusb_access() {
     usb_dev_handle *lvr_winusb;

     if(debug) {
        usb_set_debug(255);
     } else {
        usb_set_debug(0);
     }
     usb_init();
     usb_find_busses();
     usb_find_devices();


     if(!(lvr_winusb = find_lvr_winusb())) {
                printf("Couldn't find the USB device, Exiting\n");
                return NULL;
        }


        usb_detach(lvr_winusb, INTERFACE1);


        usb_detach(lvr_winusb, INTERFACE2);


        if (usb_set_configuration(lvr_winusb, 0x01) < 0) {
                printf("Could not set configuration 1\n");
                return NULL;
        }


        // Microdia tiene 2 interfaces
        if (usb_claim_interface(lvr_winusb, INTERFACE1) < 0) {
                printf("Could not claim interface\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        if (usb_claim_interface(lvr_winusb, INTERFACE2) < 0) {
                printf("Could not claim interface\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        return lvr_winusb;
}



usb_dev_handle *find_lvr_winusb() {

     struct usb_bus *bus;
        struct usb_device *dev;

        for (bus = usb_busses; bus; bus = bus->next) {
        for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next) {
                        if (dev->descriptor.idVendor == VENDOR_ID && 
                                dev->descriptor.idProduct == PRODUCT_ID ) {
                                usb_dev_handle *handle;
                                if(debug) {
                                  printf("lvr_winusb with Vendor Id: %x and Product Id: %x found.\n", VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
                                }

                                if (!(handle = usb_open(dev))) {
                                        printf("Could not open USB device\n");
                                        return NULL;
                                }
                                return handle;
                        }
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}


void ini_control_transfer(usb_dev_handle *dev) {
    int r,i;

    char question[] = { 0x01,0x01 };

    r = usb_control_msg(dev, 0x21, 0x09, 0x0201, 0x00, (char *) question, 2, timeout);
    if( r < 0 )
    {
          perror("USB control write"); bad("USB write failed"); 
    }


    if(debug) {
      for (i=0;i<reqIntLen; i++) printf("%02x ",question[i] & 0xFF);
      printf("\n");
    }
}

void control_transfer(usb_dev_handle *dev, const char *pquestion) {
    int r,i;

    char question[reqIntLen];

    memcpy(question, pquestion, sizeof question);

    r = usb_control_msg(dev, 0x21, 0x09, 0x0200, 0x01, (char *) question, reqIntLen, timeout);
    if( r < 0 )
    {
          perror("USB control write"); bad("USB write failed"); 
    }

    if(debug) {
        for (i=0;i<reqIntLen; i++) printf("%02x ",question[i]  & 0xFF);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void interrupt_transfer(usb_dev_handle *dev) {

    int r,i;
    char answer[reqIntLen];
    char question[reqIntLen];
    for (i=0;i<reqIntLen; i++) question[i]=i;
    r = usb_interrupt_write(dev, endpoint_Int_out, question, reqIntLen, timeout);
    if( r < 0 )
    {
          perror("USB interrupt write"); bad("USB write failed"); 
    }
    r = usb_interrupt_read(dev, endpoint_Int_in, answer, reqIntLen, timeout);
    if( r != reqIntLen )
    {
          perror("USB interrupt read"); bad("USB read failed"); 
    }

    if(debug) {
       for (i=0;i<reqIntLen; i++) printf("%i, %i, \n",question[i],answer[i]);
    }

    usb_release_interface(dev, 0);
}

void interrupt_read(usb_dev_handle *dev) {

    int r,i;
    unsigned char answer[reqIntLen];
    bzero(answer, reqIntLen);

    r = usb_interrupt_read(dev, 0x82, answer, reqIntLen, timeout);
    if( r != reqIntLen )
    {
          perror("USB interrupt read"); bad("USB read failed"); 
    }

    if(debug) {
       for (i=0;i<reqIntLen; i++) printf("%02x ",answer[i]  & 0xFF);

       printf("\n");
    }
}

void interrupt_read_temperatura(usb_dev_handle *dev, float *tempC) {

    int r,i, temperature;
    unsigned char answer[reqIntLen];
    bzero(answer, reqIntLen);

    r = usb_interrupt_read(dev, 0x82, answer, reqIntLen, timeout);
    if( r != reqIntLen )
    {
          perror("USB interrupt read"); bad("USB read failed"); 
    }


    if(debug) {
      for (i=0;i<reqIntLen; i++) printf("%02x ",answer[i]  & 0xFF);

      printf("\n");
    }

    temperature = (answer[3] & 0xFF) + (answer[2] << 8);
    *tempC = temperature * (125.0 / 32000.0);

}

void bulk_transfer(usb_dev_handle *dev) {

    int r,i;
    char answer[reqBulkLen];

    r = usb_bulk_write(dev, endpoint_Bulk_out, NULL, 0, timeout);
    if( r < 0 )
    {
          perror("USB bulk write"); bad("USB write failed"); 
    }
    r = usb_bulk_read(dev, endpoint_Bulk_in, answer, reqBulkLen, timeout);
    if( r != reqBulkLen )
    {
          perror("USB bulk read"); bad("USB read failed"); 
    }


    if(debug) {
      for (i=0;i<reqBulkLen; i++) printf("%02x ",answer[i]  & 0xFF);
    }

    usb_release_interface(dev, 0);
}


void ex_program(int sig) {
      bsalir=1;

      (void) signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
}

int main( int argc, char **argv) {

     usb_dev_handle *lvr_winusb = NULL;
     float tempc;
     int c;
     struct tm *local;
     time_t t;

     while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "mfcvhl::")) != -1)
     switch (c)
       {
       case 'v':
         debug = 1;
         break;
       case 'c':
         formato=1; //Celsius
         break;
       case 'f':
         formato=2; //Fahrenheit
         break;
       case 'm':
         mrtg=1;
         break;
       case 'l':
         if (optarg!=NULL){
           if (!sscanf(optarg,"%i",&seconds)==1) {
             fprintf (stderr, "Error: '%s' is not numeric.\n", optarg);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           } else {           
              bsalir = 0;
              break;
           }
         } else {
           bsalir = 0;
           seconds = 5;
           break;
         }
       case '?':
       case 'h':
         printf("pcsensor version %s\n",VERSION);
     printf("      Aviable options:\n");
     printf("          -h help\n");
     printf("          -v verbose\n");
     printf("          -l[n] loop every 'n' seconds, default value is 5s\n");
     printf("          -c output only in Celsius\n");
     printf("          -f output only in Fahrenheit\n");
     printf("          -m output for mrtg integration\n");

     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       default:
         if (isprint (optopt))
           fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
         else
           fprintf (stderr,
                    "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                    optopt);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

     if (optind < argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Non-option ARGV-elements, try -h for help.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     if ((lvr_winusb = setup_libusb_access()) == NULL) {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     } 

     (void) signal(SIGINT, ex_program);

     ini_control_transfer(lvr_winusb);

     control_transfer(lvr_winusb, uTemperatura );
     interrupt_read(lvr_winusb);

     control_transfer(lvr_winusb, uIni1 );
     interrupt_read(lvr_winusb);

     control_transfer(lvr_winusb, uIni2 );
     interrupt_read(lvr_winusb);
     interrupt_read(lvr_winusb);



     do {
           control_transfer(lvr_winusb, uTemperatura );
           interrupt_read_temperatura(lvr_winusb, &tempc);
        tempc = (tempc - substract);

           t = time(NULL);
           local = localtime(&t);

           if (mrtg) {
              if (formato==2) {
                  printf("%.2f\n", (9.0 / 5.0 * tempc + 32.0));
                  printf("%.2f\n", (9.0 / 5.0 * tempc + 32.0));
              } else {
                  printf("%.2f\n", tempc);
                  printf("%.2f\n", tempc);
              }

              printf("%02d:%02d\n", 
                          local->tm_hour,
                          local->tm_min);

              printf("pcsensor\n");
           } else {
              if (formato==2) {
                  printf("%.2f\n", (9.0 / 5.0 * tempc + 32.0));
              } else if (formato==1) {
                  printf("%.2f\n", tempc);
              } else {
                  printf("%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d ", 
                              local->tm_year +1900, 
                              local->tm_mon + 1, 
                              local->tm_mday,
                              local->tm_hour,
                              local->tm_min,
                              local->tm_sec);

                  printf("Temperature %.2fF %.2fC\n", (9.0 / 5.0 * tempc + 32.0), tempc);
              }
           }

           if (!bsalir)
              sleep(seconds);
     } while (!bsalir);

     usb_release_interface(lvr_winusb, INTERFACE1);
     usb_release_interface(lvr_winusb, INTERFACE2);

     usb_close(lvr_winusb); 

     return 0; 
}
```

As the sensor version is different, probably USB write control too different. I don't know USB controlling much. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, but I'm going to assume your trying to use that node code in a Node-Red Function node. You can't use requires in a Node-Red function block. If you want to include extra modules you need to add them to the end of the settings.js file so they get included in the context object. e.g.

```
functionGlobalContext: { bonescript:require('bonescript') }
```

You would access the bonescript object like this:

```
context.global.bonescript
```

Having said that, you probably shouldn't be doing this in a function node, you should look at writing a input node. You can find the doc for writing nodes here: http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/

Comment: Yes, I am working on node-red and I added already in settings
`functionGlobalContext: { thermometers:require('temper1') }`
I have written the function in function block to get temperature as:
`var device = context.global.thermometers.readTemperature("0002:0004:00", function(err, value) {
  console.log("Result:"+value);
});
return device;`

Comment: But it is showing can not open device with this path, wheras the path is correct as I tested with this command : 
`var devices = context.global.thermometers.getDevices();`
and did `return devices;` got the path and added.